# JDBC Redshift Driver Class Not Found

Tags: java, r, amazon-redshift

To preface, yes, I have seen and read the multiple very similar questions that have been asked before, but due to my inexperience and almost non existent java knowledge I really am not understanding what is happening in my case.

So here it goes:

I am trying to connect R to a redshift server on Mac OS X 10.11.6.

I have installed rJava and RJDBC packages for starters. I have downloaded the latest jdbc driver and am running the latest version of Java (1.8).

Here is the code I am using:

```
library("rJava")
library("RJDBC")

download.file('https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/RedshiftJDBC42-1.1.17.1017.jar','RedshiftJDBC42-1.1.17.1017.jar')

drv <- JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver", "/Users/edwards/Documents/RedshiftJDBC42-1.1.17.1017.jar", identifier.quote="`")
```

And the error I get:

```
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
```

I have tried a few troubleshooting tips in the other threads but still cannot get to the bottom of this problem. I have no problem connecting to the server in SQLWorkbench J, but my tool of choice for analysis is R and I would really like to get this driver issue resolved so I can connect to the server.

My java -version returns:

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

Using:

```
.jclassLoader()$setDebug(1L)
```

I was able to see this when running the line that retrieves the driver:

```
RJavaClassLoader: added '/Users/edwards/Documents/RedshiftJDBC42-1.1.17.1017.jar' to the URL class path loader
RJavaClassLoader: adding Java archive file '/Users/edwards/Documents/RedshiftJDBC42-1.1.17.1017.jar' to the internal class path
RJavaClassLoader: added '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RJDBC/java/RJDBC.jar' to the URL class path loader
RJavaClassLoader: adding Java archive file '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RJDBC/java/RJDBC.jar' to the internal class path
RJavaClassLoader@2666e815.findClass(com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver)
```

Once again I am not well versed on these things and I am rather lost, so if any additional info is needed or you think my issue has been resolved in another thread let me know!

Thanks in advance!